¿Cómo podría lograr un orden "intercalado" en esta consulta de MySQL?
En mi tabla tengo una columna llamada groupID con series de valores como estos:
groupID
----------
107010101
107010201
107010301
...
108010101
108010201
108010301
...
107020101
107020201
107020301
...
108020101
108020201
108020301
...

Y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de ordenar los valores de forma "intercalada" por llamarlo de algún modo, haciendo que ordene por las cifras 4, 5, 6 y 7 y a la vez "intercalando" las cifras 2, y 3 o sea: 070101, 080101, 070102, 080102, 070103, 080103, etc.
Si ejecuto:
SELECT * 
FROM `lh_office_biblical_join` 
ORDER BY `groupID`;

Me da estos resultados:
| groupID   | 
|----------:|
| 107010101 |
| 107010201 |
| 107010301 |
  ...
| 107020101 |
| 107020201 |
| 107020301 |
  ...
| 108010101 |
| 108010201 |
| 108010301 |
  ...
| 108020101 |
| 108020201 |
| 108020301 |

Pero yo quiero algo así:
| groupID   | 
|----------:|
| 107010101 |
| 108010101 |
| 107010201 |
| 108010201 |
| 107010301 |
| 108010301 |
  ...
| 107020101 |
| 108020101 |
| 107020201 |
| 108020201 |
| 107020301 |
| 108020301 |

¿Cómo podría lograrlo?
Aquí dejo un fiddle:
CREATE TABLE `lh_office_biblical_join` (
    `groupID` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 );

INSERT INTO `lh_office_biblical_join`  (`groupID`) VALUES 
  (107010101),(107010201),(107010301),(107010401),(107010501),(107010601),(107010701),
  (108010101),(108010201),(108010301),(108010401),(108010501),(108010601),(108010701),
  (107020101),(107020201),(107020301),(107020401),(107020501),(107020601),(107020701),
  (108020101),(108020201),(108020301),(108020401),(108020501),(108020601),(108020701);

SELECT * FROM `lh_office_biblical_join` ORDER BY `groupID`;





groupID




107010101


107010201


107010301


107010401


107010501


107010601


107010701


107020101


107020201


107020301


107020401


107020501


107020601


107020701


108010101


108010201


108010301


108010401


108010501


108010601


108010701


108020101


108020201


108020301


108020401


108020501


108020601


108020701



fiddle

decime si estas son tus reglas.. en pseudo no.. ordenar por substr(posicion 7) luego por substr(posicion 3) luego por substr(posicion 5).. asi serian las reglas????

@gbianchi no sabría cómo explicártelo en pseudo código. Quiero ordenar primero por las cifras 4, 5, 6 y 7 además de ir intercalando en ese orden el valor de las cifras 2 y 3. Me hice un poco de lío en la redacción inicial de la pregunta.

Ya que las cifras significativas para el ordenamiento son las 6 últimas, entonces se puede hacer un ordenamiento por módulo value % 1,000,000 y luego por el mismo número en si.
SELECT * FROM `lh_office_biblical_join` 
ORDER BY MOD(`groupID`, 1000000), `groupID`;

groupID
107010101
108010101
107010201
108010201
107010301
108010301
...
107020601
108020601
107020701
108020701



Elegante solución, y funciona del modo esperado. ¡Mil gracias!

No estoy totalmente seguro de la respuesta, pero he revisado lo que quieres vs lo que obtuve alrededor de 10 veces ya.
Usando SUBSTRING es posible ordenar una parte de la data, y luego el resto.
SELECT * 
FROM `lh_office_biblical_join`
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(groupID, 5, 5),
         SUBSTRING(groupID, 1, 4);

Primero, con SUBSTRING(groupID, 5, 5) ordenamos los últimos 5 digitos.
Luego intercalamos SUBSTRING(groupID, 1, 4) para los primeros 4.
De este modo ordenamos el subgrupo, y el grupo.
Al final, una imagen del resultado en tu fiddle, espero haber entendido bien el desafío.

Edit: Volví a revisar el orden de números solicitados y sus posiciones, así que agregaré lo que entendí de ello acá abajo.
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING(groupID, 4, 4),
    SUBSTRING(groupID, 2, 2);



Este orden arroja el resultado esperado ORDER BY SUBSTRING(groupID, 4, 4), SUBSTRING(groupID, 2, 2) Perdón por haberme liado un poco en la redacción.

Tranquilo, a todos nos pasa. Del mismo modo yo miré primero la solución, antes de entender el orden necesitado.
